# How to get context when application off?

Tags: android

In firebase messaging system, the `onMessageReceived()`method run when application off and get a push notification. So I want to use SQLite in `onMessageReceived()` method. SQLite must require a context, But I can't get an ApplicationContext in the method because of application is off. How to get application context when application off?

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(FirebaseMessagingService.this);
        database.updateTicket(Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("idx")));

        try{
            Badges.setBadge(this, 1);
        }catch(BadgesNotSupportedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = "Default";

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

        //sendPushNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
    }
```

This is my onMessageReceived Code. The problem is database code where first two lines are doesn't work. I already checked it works on application on or application run on background.

Comment: you sure the values are correct `Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("idx"))` here ?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yes. I checked it works on application on or application run on background.

Comment: you support to explain the error and expected behavior and use logs(or debug code) to verify the control flow and values, context has nothing to do with this

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Ok, I'll try another solution. Thanks

Comment: typo you `suppose*`  and try using `Update current` instead of `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

Answer (score 1):

Services has their own context and as [`FirebaseMessagingService` **extends Service**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)
 so you can use `this` or `YourServiceClassName.this`

Comment: But I can't access at SQLite despite use like `DatabaseHelper database = new Database(this);` in onMessagingReceived. This is when application off. Run correctly when Application run on or on background.

Comment: post the error details or explain the issue and expected behavior(edit your question and append it)